# Run macro if button is not clicked in certain amount of time

Tags: vba, excel

I have 3 spreadsheets that I am auto-opening every morning using the task scheduler. Upon opening, I have used VBA to automatically update, save, and then close each file.

The code to do this works perfectly, but causes some hassle if I want to open the spreadsheets to edit them (I have to open them specially to not run the macro and therefore automatically close). I want to be able to open the spreadsheets normally for editing without them closing automatically.

A possible solution is to have a MsgBox pop up. If the MsgBox is not acknowledged within 15 seconds (or so), then the file automatically closes. If the MsgBox is acknowledged, then the file does not close.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You can open the workbook by pressing SHIFT. That ways the macro will not run. Msgbox option is not a viable option as when the message box is shown then the entire code will come to a stand still. Excel macro cannot run asynchronously. What you could do however is show a userform which can auto close in 15 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm trying to show a userform that will give the user to the option to check a box to keep the spreadsheet open. If the user has not checked the box after 15 seconds, I want the spreadsheet to save and close.

I'm having some issues writing the code for this. Can you help?

Comment: Please re-read my comment above again.

Comment: Please excuse my misunderstanding. I am very new to this.

How do I get a userform to auto close after 15 seconds?

Comment: This will get you started. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165.aspx

Answer (score 1):

First
Create a sub routine with name (Close) with following code

```
Unload UserForm1
```

Second : call that routine after 15 seconds

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 
    tmeKill = Time + TimeValue("00:00:15")      
    Application.OnTime tmeKill, "Close" 
End Sub
```